# Generalization of $(a+b)^2\leq 2(a^2+b^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

We know that, $(a+b)^2\leq 2(a^2+b^2)$. Do we have anything similar for $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^N a_i\right)^2.$$
where $a_i\in \mathbb{R}\ \ \ \ \forall\ i\in \{1,\cdots,N\}$.

For $n=3$, we get
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
(a_1+a_2+a_3)^2&\leq 2\left((a_1+a_2)^2+a_3^2\right)
\\&\leq 2\left(2(a_1^2+a_2^2)+a_3^2 \right).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Do we have some sort of generalization?

Comment: Your generalization to $n=3$ is correct, but not symmetric in the variables. A symmetric one would be interesting. Good question.

Comment: The equality for $n=2$ is equivalent to $0\leq (a-b)^2$ so a possible generalizations would be $0 \leq (a-b)^2 + (b-c)^2 + (c-a)^2$  and so on (which expanded can be brought on a form similar to what you have). We also have (Cauchy–Schwarz): $(a_1+\ldots+a_n)^2 \leq n(a_1^2+\ldots+a_n^2)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's C-S:
$$n(a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_n^2)=$$
$$=(1^2+1^2+...+1^2)(a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_n^2)\geq(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)^2.$$

Comment: And if the asker is not familiar, C-S is the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).

Comment: So simple! I knew this generalization but wasn't able to find a proof. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Abhinav Jha You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Others have mentioned this formula already but I want to remark that we can strengthen it a bit to
$$
|a_1|+\cdots+|a_n| \le \sqrt{n}\,\left(a_1^2+\cdots+a_n^2 \right)^{1/2}.
$$
Moreover, the "other direction" we also have
$$
\left(a_1^2+\cdots+a_n^2 \right)^{1/2} \le |a_1|+\cdots+|a_n|,
$$
which follows from super-additivity of $x\mapsto x^2$ on $[0,\infty)$. Together they show that these two [norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm) on $\Bbb R^n$ ($||\cdot||_1$ and $||\cdot||_2$) are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The generalization is

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^N a_i\right)^2\le N\sum_{i=1}^N a_i^2$$
which degenerates to equality if all $a_i$ are equal. It is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality applied to vectors $(1,1,\dots,1)$ and $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$.